# How do I remap folder to different folder in URL?

Tags: 7, navigation, .htaccess

I have developed website in Drupal. There is folder(e.g., my-demo) which contains few PHP files which are developed in plain PHP. The my-demo directory is placed in the Drupal root directory.

Now I want to access this folder in a menu. If I put http://example.com/my-demo, it is accessible. I want the folder path to be like http://example.com/product-details/my-demo in the menu, without creating the product-details directory, because I have already mapped product-details to a path alias.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is your drupal version and what is your webserver?

Comment: @ zhilevan Drupal 7.5, Server is apache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with remapping in .htaccess

Find this code:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
```

And add this line after it:

```
RewriteRule ^product-details/my-demo/(.*) my-demo/$1
```

So the complete version will be:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^product-details/my-demo/(.*) my-demo/$1
```

See [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html) for more examples.